# Given a set A in which all elements are of the form: $x+y \sqrt3$; $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$. What structure can you define...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, binary-operations

Given a set $A$ in which all elements are of the form: $x+y \sqrt3$, $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

What algebraic structure can you define with operations of addition and multiplication?

I am stuck figuring how to interpret  $x+y \sqrt3$ and use it to prove  the properties of algebraic structures... so any help would be sincerely appreciate.

Comment: are you familiar with rings and fields?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner with rings yes, with fields, not yet

Comment: every element of $A$ is a real number, so $A$ can be realized as a subset of the ring $\mathbb{R}$ in a natural way. now, how do two elements of $A$ multiply and add together, considered as elements of $\mathbb{R}$? can you use this to show that $A$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$? (ie, can you show that $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is closed under addition, subtraction, and multiplication, and that it contains $1$?) if so, then $A$ with the multiplication and addition inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ forms a ring

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, This is a good approach to the problem, in that case I don't need to prove that $A$ is group in first palce and so on?, since all that characteristics are inherited from $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: you should demonstrate closure, but other properties (associative, commutative, distributive) are inherited from $\mathbb R$

Comment: @lurker507 yep, exactly! :) as J. W. Tanner says, the only thing you need to show is closure of the operations, since all of the ring axioms will be inherited by subsets closed under those operations. (this is a special property shared by a lot of the objects of study in algebra, and there is a term for it in first-order logic. namely, the first-order theory of rings in the language $\{+,\cdot,-,0,1\}$ is "universal" – every axiom holds in any "substructure" (ie any subset closed under those operations and containing the constant symbols $0$ and $1$))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ease, I will write $r=\sqrt{3}$, so $r^2=3$.

**Addition:**

- It is closed: $$(x+yr)+(a+br) = (x+a)+(y+b)r$$ since $x+a$ and $y+b$ are again rational.
- $0$ is neutral element.
- $-x-yr$ is opposite to $x+yr$
- Clearly it is associative and commutative so it is Abel group for addition.

**Multiplication:**

- It is closed: $$(x+yr)\cdot (a+br) = (xa+3yb)+(xb+ya)r$$ since $xa+3by$ and $xb+ya$ are again rational.
- $1$ is neutral element for multiplication.
- Inverse to $x+yr\ne 0$ is $${x-ry\over x^2+3y^2}$$
- Clearly it is associative and commutative.
- And multiplication is distributive over addition...

So it is a field.

Notice that you can replace $\sqrt{3}$ with any $\sqrt{q}$ where $q$ is rational number which is not a square of rational number.

Comment: and multiplication is distributive over addition

Comment: Thanks @J.W.Tanner

Comment: thank you @aqua, this is very helpful